# Opentelemetry target allocator does not allocate discovered ServiceMonitors

Tags: prometheus, metrics, open-telemetry

I have deployed an Opentelemetry collector using the following:

```
apiVersion: opentelemetry.io/v1alpha1
kind: OpenTelemetryCollector
metadata:
  name: otel-metrics
  namespace: otel-metrics
spec:
  mode: statefulset
  targetAllocator:
    enabled: true
    serviceAccount: opentelemetry-targetallocator-sa
    prometheusCR:
      enabled: true
  config: |
    receivers:
      prometheus:
        config:
          scrape_configs:
          - job_name: 'otel-metrics'
            scrape_interval: 30s
            static_configs:
            - targets: [ '0.0.0.0:8888' ]

    exporters:
      logging:
        verbosity: detailed
      prometheus:
        endpoint: "0.0.0.0:8889"
        send_timestamps: true
        metric_expiration: 180m

    service:
      pipelines:
        metrics:
          receivers:
          - prometheus
          processors: []
          exporters:
          - logging
          - prometheus
      telemetry:
        logs:
          level: "debug"
```

However when I look at the configmap for the collector, I can see that the URL it has created is only looking for jobs for `otel-metrics`:

```
collector.yaml: |
  exporters:
    logging:
      verbosity: detailed
    prometheus:
      endpoint: 0.0.0.0:8889
      metric_expiration: 180m
      send_timestamps: true
  receivers:
    prometheus:
      config:
        scrape_configs:
        - http_sd_configs:
          - url: http://otel-metrics-targetallocator:80/jobs/otel-metrics/targets?collector_id=$POD_NAME
          job_name: otel-metrics
  service:
    pipelines:
      metrics:
        exporters:
        - logging
        - prometheus
        processors: []
        receivers:
        - prometheus
    telemetry:
      logs:
        level: debug
```

If I curl the endpoint `http://otel-metrics-targetallocator:80/jobs`, I can see that there are a bunch of jobs (e.g. the following), but these are obviously not being picked up by the collector as the URL is only scoping to the `otel-metrics` jobs. Below is an example of some of the jobs:

```
"serviceMonitor/monitoring/node-exporter/0": {
  "_link": "/jobs/serviceMonitor%2Fmonitoring%2Fnode-exporter%2F0/targets"
},
"serviceMonitor/cert-manager/cert-manager-service-monitor/0": {
  "_link": "/jobs/serviceMonitor%2Fcert-manager%2Fcert-manager-service-monitor%2F0/targets"
},
"serviceMonitor/monitoring/kube-state-metrics/0": {
  "_link": "/jobs/serviceMonitor%2Fmonitoring%2Fkube-state-metrics%2F0/targets"
},
```

If I curl just the URL that is injected into the config map, `http://otel-metrics-targetallocator:80/jobs/otel-metrics/targets?collector_id=$POD_NAME`, I can see that there is only one job:

```
{
  "otel-metrics-collector-0": {
    "_link": "/jobs/otel-metrics/targets?collector_id=otel-metrics-collector-0",
    "targets": []
  }
}
```

I am not sure if it is relevant, but the other jobs are from a different namespace than what the otel collector and operator are deployed in. How can I get the target allocator to put all the serviceMonitors under one job so they can be picked up by one collector?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you don't have a target allocator block in your prometheus configuration ([see here for an example](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-operator/tree/main/cmd/otel-allocator#prometheuscr-specifics)), adding that will tell your collector to discover those service monitor jobs. We also have alpha support for automatically doing this by setting a featuregate on your operator deployment ([example](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-operator/blob/282c169f0499694dd0b780cf225bc8680c05071d/README.md?plain=1#L633-L660)). I think it's probably time that featuregate is moved to beta, I have opened [an issue](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-operator/issues/2208) to say exactly that :)

Specifically, the missing block is:

```yaml
  config: |
    receivers:
      prometheus:
        config:
          scrape_configs:
          - job_name: 'otel-collector'
        target_allocator:
          endpoint: http://my-targetallocator-service
          interval: 30s
          collector_id: "${POD_NAME}"
```

setting the target_allocator block is what informs the collector to pull new jobs discovered from servicemonitors from the target allocator

Comment: I was following this example: https://opentelemetry.io/docs/kubernetes/operator/target-allocator/#getting-started. The operator is supposed to inject the target allocator spec into the configmap. The second snippet I posted is from the rendered configmap which has the http_sd endpoint

Comment: Yes, i see that. I updated my answer to be more clear. LMK if that helps.

Comment: Thank you @jaronoff97. It looks like the operator is injecting the target_allocator address into the config map correctly (I have updated the question with more detail), however the target allocator URL is just for a single job rather than all jobs that it has.

Comment: You were absolutely right, I was missing the feature gate. The necessary helm command needed `--set manager.featureGates=operator.collector.rewritetargetallocator`

Comment: This took me so long to work out. I have added a PR to the helm chart readme to help anyone else: https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-helm-charts/pull/918

Comment: Ah great, thank you so much for upstreaming the PR. I really appreciate better docs :) Thank you!